# How to cross-compile a autotools project for ARM?

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, gnu-make, autotools

I am looking to cross-compile an existing library which uses GNU autotools build system. I have a Linaro arm-gcc toolchain installed in my host machine and I am able to compile small programs directly using arm-gcc.

- **Host machine:** Ubuntu 12.04 Intel x64
- **Target machine:** Ubuntu 14.04 ARM 32-bit (a board similar to Raspberry-Pi)

I have a library source code which has configure.ac and Makefile.am files for it. I want to compile this code on host machine and generate ARM binaries which can be copied over to the target platform.

What is the canonical way to do this?

For specifics, I am looking for something that would work for a "Hello World" application/library in C cross-compiled using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc and autotools.

Comment: Can you provide library name which you want to cross compile?

Comment: Its a proprietary library code at work not open to public. I am looking for an answer that applies to "any" library which needs to be cross-compiled using autotools and arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Comment: does that library have configure file?

Comment: There are standard autotool variables; However, in order for everything to be perfect, the input to autotools has to be correct (Ie, the projects configure.ac, etc).  You can use the `--host=` and `--build=` options.  The [standard environment variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#index-configuration-variables_002c-overriding) can be over-ridden, to add your compiler prefix, add include directories, etc.  You may need to have a shadow rootfs for includes and linking.  There is no *canonical way* as software is different.  Provide real world issues.

Comment: Sure, I get that there are `--host` and `--build` options in autotools, but I could not find a good tutorial on how to use those. Its true that requirements might be different across libraries. I am looking for something that would work for an "Hello World" application in C, So I can extrapolate that for more complex software.

Comment: I am also trying something similar these days!
Can you help @PunitSoni?

Answer (score 4):

```
--build=`./config.guess` --host=arm-linux-gnueabi
```

might be sufficient, as it will look for a corresponding ARM toolchain. Otherwise, try adding: `CC="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc"`

You can also add: `CFLAGS="-pipe -Wall -O2 ... <other arm-gcc flags>"`
for better code optimization.

Comment: I think one of the most important flags when cross-compiling is `--sysroot` so the correct headers  and libraries are found. You should proably provide details of setting it for a cross-compile.

Answer (score 3):

The right way to do this on Ubuntu is to the use the distro-supplied cross-compiler, not a 3rd party one like Linaro. You only need an out-of-distro package when the distro one is not good enough for some reason (like you need some cutting-edge feature which is only in the Linaro toolchain and not yet in the distro). Hardly anyone needs to do that.

Install the gcc, g++ crosstollchains, a cross libc and some config tools with:

```
apt install crossbuild-essential-armhf
```

If the software you want to build needs nothing more than the C runtime library then you can build it as is. If it needs anything more then you need to install cross-build-dependencies.

- If the software you want to build is packaged (and called `$packagename`), you should be able to:

  ```
  dpkg --add-architecture armhf
  apt update
  apt build-dep $packagename
  ```

  then build it with

  ```
  dpkg-buildpackage -aarmhf
  ```
- If it's not packaged you'll need to install build-dependencies, libraries for arch armhf, tools for the native arch (usually amd64 or arm64).  For example:

  ```
  apt-get install sgmltools ghostscript libpng-dev:armhf libssl-dev:armhf
  ```

  would install native `ghostscript` and `sgmltools` (for doc-building) and headers/libraries for `libpng` and `libssl` for armhf.

More details [on the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossCompiling).